# Oozie coordinator not able to launch workflow during time based trigger

Tags: azure, oozie

We have set up a new ambari cluster with hortornworks H.D.P 3.1.1 and oozie 4.3.1

Oozie is not able to read the configuration from cluster and giving the error message when coordinator is triggering workflow action.

E0904: Scheme [abfs] not supported in uri [abfs:/

action info :

```
"nominalTime": "Thu, 05 Dec 2019 07:00:00 GMT",
"trackerUri": null,
"lastModifiedTime": "Thu, 05 Dec 2019 07:00:00 GMT",
"coordJobId": "0000000-191204172009576-oozie-oozi-C",
"missingDependencies": "",
"createdConf": null,
"errorMessage": "E0904: Scheme [abfs] not supported in uri [abfs://]",
"externalId": null,
"errorCode": "E1005",
"type": null,
"pushMissingDependencies": "",
"consoleUrl": null,
"runConf": null,
"actionNumber": 6,
"createdTime": "Thu, 05 Dec 2019 06:55:12 GMT",
"toString": "CoordinatorAction name[0000000-191204172009576-oozie-oozi-C@6] status[FAILED]",
"id": "0000000-191204172009576-oozie-oozi-C@6",
"externalStatus": null,
"status": "FAILED"
```

Comment: From the tiny log fragment shown, looks like the JAR defining the _Azure Data Lake Storage_ connector is not present in the CLASSPATH of the Oozie server. If it is not part of the **default** HDP bundle then you have to manage it manually, outside of Ambari.

Comment: Hi Samson, but when we are rerunning the coordinator action using an action number from the command line, strangely it is able to launch the workflow. If the issue is with the CLASSPATH, it should fail in this case also, right? And also the only error log from the Oozie is the fragment that I have pasted. Is there any place where I can search for the coordinator specific logs?

Comment: The Coordinator and Workflow logic run _inside_ of the Oozie server.

Comment: can you help me with the Oozie package which trigger the workflow based on time? Basically I want to check how the trigger and rerun are different in submitting the application. I have added the more log. errorCode and errorMessage are different in the logs.

Comment: You must inspect the logs of the Oozie service, on the node running Oozie, usually inside `/var/log/oozie/`. And possibly bump its Log4J configuration to _`DEBUG`_ level...